# How loud until you get a mark on your back?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, colleagues, work-life-balance

Being relatively skilled and relatively loud in the office at promoting myself has got me in several rollercoasters of raising through the ranks then falling :) But one thing with being loud is inevitable and it is that sooner or later there is a mark on your back.

Being silent does not help either as you never end up doing something of significance. Being loud on the other hand does not come without complications.

Where is the sweet spot ?

Comment: Weren't you elected and accepted as your team leader? That doesn't seem like falling through ranks.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul look it is fine that you don't like me. Maybe you should considering avoiding me :) In this post I am not talking about my current project but it is a retrospective of my 20 years experience. Yes i have raised and falled multiple times in my 20 years.

Comment: What does "being loud" actually mean?

Comment: @joeqwerty that is a bit direct english translation. It basicly means that you are good making yourself visible which usualy involves promoting yourself taking an argument now and then, being available and interacting with as many as possible people.

Comment: Similar to the use of ‚loud‘ to describe bright, or ‚tacky’ colours, it‘s mostly a way to say ‚making yourself seen‘

Answer (score 1):

You should only fail if you exaggerate your skill and can't live up to your mouth. That's the difference between coming across as confident and competent versus 'just a loud mouth'.

But either way expect a mark on your back and have strategies to deal with it.

> Where is the sweet spot ?

The sweet spot is anywhere up until your arrogance outstrips your ability. This includes soft skills.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, employees don't 'rise and fall' through the ranks roller-coaster style through a typical 20 year stretch.  Even 'loud' (which I'll take to mean self-touting and confident) employees don't.

**In my mind, this is likely due to one thing: inability to understand your own weaknesses and limitations.**

In other words, it sounds like you accepted positions, projects, etc that you didn't have the ability to deliver on.  You got elevated upwards because of your results and your self-promotion... but ask yourself: why were you demoted?  Generally, demotions are a *very rare thing*, especially since it tends to kill morale for the person being demoted.

So your question is about a "Mark On Your Back".  I'd say it's easier if you actually identify what the 'Mark' itself is.  It's not being Confident/Self-Promotional/etc.  There are all sorts of people that have that trait that don't have the same problem you do.  The 'Mark' is: "Pesho is always promising something, but ultimately fails to live up to it."

**If you think about it that way, the answer is pretty simple: spend some time figuring out *why* you failed or were demoted, address the weaknesses that caused it, and then go from there - with the idea of reducing your failure rate.**  Did you take a suddenly open position without having the necessary skill set, hoping you'd grow into it?  Did you aggressively promise delivery on something but then fall victim to planning fallacy?  Did you stake your reputation on something that turned out to be wrong?  Etc, etc.  Figure out what you're systematically doing wrong that's causing a rollercoaster ride of failures, and fix it.